# HTML CSS Multiple Classes Width/Height/Size not set

Tags: css, html

I am trying to create a div, that is created by adding multiple classes.
For a particulair reason, the width, height and size will not set. Instead they are the auto-size. When I add everything to one class, the size and such work, but as stated earlier when seperated, they will not do anything.

How I created the multiclass div (tried shuffeling the classes aswell)

```
<div class="box pos1 1x1">
<p class="verdana"> ... </p>
</div>
```

Inside the CSS file:

```
.pos1{
    display: inline; float:left;
}

.1x1 {
    width:13.5vw;
    height:13.5vw;
}

.1x2 {
    width:13.5vw;
    height:17.5vw;
}

.2x2 {
    width:17.5vw;
    height:17.5vw;
}

div.box{
    background-color:#000000; color: white;
    margin-left:0.25vw; margin-top:0px; margin-right:0.25vw; margin-bottom:0px;
    border: white solid 2px;  
}
```

Also creating one big class is not an option.

Thank you.

Comment: Classnames cannot start with a number...start there.

Comment: Mmm, seems like that sovled the whole thing. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Paulie_D - You can if you escape it properly https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gc5j590z/. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6732899/616443. https://mothereff.in/css-escapes

Comment: @j08691 Well yes, but I think that's a little advanced here. Start 'em slow. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class names starting with numbers are not valid! Your class name have to start with `_`, `-` or a letter (`a-z`)!

The pattern to validate a class name: `-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*`

> https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner

**See the following solution:**

```css
.pos1{
  display:inline; 
  float:left;
}
.size1x1 {
  width:13.5vw;
  height:13.5vw;
}
.size1x2 {
  width:13.5vw;
  height:17.5vw;
}
.size2x2 {
  width:17.5vw;
  height:17.5vw;
}
div.box{
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
  margin:0 0.25vw;
  border:2px solid #fff;  
}
```

```html
<div class="box pos1 size1x1">
  <p class="verdana"> ... </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As other mentioned class name cannot start with numbers, and in `pos1` you make the div to display as `inline`. Inline element does not have height, should use `inline-block`.